# Debian Lenny: Want Splashy to start directly after Grub2

Tags: linux, debian, grub2

I'm running a GNU/Linux Debian Lenny with an 2.6.26-2-686 kernel.
I installed splashy for a bootsplash an updated grub to version 2.

Now I want splashy to start directly after the user has selected a startoption in grub. At the moment, when the user selects a start option a black screen with bootmessages occurs. I want it so that these messages are displayed in splashy. Or as an alternative, I want to define a background image which is displayed at this phase.

Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try [plymouth](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouthoccluded), according to its page:

> ...the boot messages are completely
>   occluded.

Comment: here is a correct link for plymouth http://cgit.freedesktop.org/plymouth/

Answer (score 0):

While plymouth is certainly worth looking into, I use it myself, let's see if we can't actually answer this question for splashy....

You need to make sure that the keyword `splash` is passed as a kernel argument at boot. This can be added at boot time or in the configuration for your bootloader (i.e. `/boot/grub/menu.lst` for grub, `/etc/lilo.conf` for lilo, or `/etc/default/grub` for grub2).

You may also have to enable the framebuffer on your kernel. To do so, you need to add another parameter to the kernel arguments: `vga=791` This argument is most likely unneeded with newer kernels in Squeeze and Sid with KMS enabled.

So the line in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` might look like this:

```
kernel  /vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-686 root=/dev/mapper/bootdisk-root00 ro quiet vga=791 splash
```

Further documentation for splashy can be found here in case you run into other issues:

http://splashy.alioth.debian.org/wiki/faq

Comment: with the whole [KMS](http://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting) thing, you realy don't want to enable the framebuffer...

Comment: Right, but I don't think that KMS is enabled in Lenny. In fact your own link says "a kernel image ≥ 2.6.29 (in Sid since 2009-04-04)" while this user has an 2.6.26 kernel. I'll edit above to be a bit more clear.